Why can't the RF impedance be adjusted to 50 Ω？


I designed a PCB for UWB which use the NXP's NCJ29D6, and when I get the PCBA, I started to match the impedance of port of NCJ29D6 at 8 GHz.
However, I found it is hard to pull the impedance from the inductive region to the ideal 50 Ω.
I thought that according to the principle of impedance matching, connecting capacitors in series or parallel could adjust the port to the ideal impedance, but no matter what devices (capacitors or inductors) are actually added, the impedance is not affected at all. (see figure1and 2)
I have successfully debugged impedance matching up to 2.4 GHz before, but the 8 GHz matching circuit is my first attempt.
Do you have any precautions?
Why is impedance debugging so strange?
Layout please see figure 3.


Are you sure the capactitors and/or inductors you are using will behave as the intended capacitors/inductors at those higher frequencies ? Also, unfortunately without having some idea of what your PCB layout looks like for the RF parts it would be hard to tell otherwise ...

Oh, the frequency of inductor are typical >8GHz from 1.3-10nH (which is LQW15AN series of Murata).

But for capacitors , i don't know which parameters would cause different result in RF-MATCHING,I used GCM15 series(C0G) of Murata .

Hi，I have updated my Layout image, and if you see it, I am willing to accept any suggestions

How are you making connection to the PCB and VNA?

I use a 50 ohm coaxial cable as the connecting cable for the VNA and PCB matching circuit. The coaxial shielded wire is connected to the ground of the PCB, the inner core is connected to the antenna feed point of the PCB, and the other end of the coaxial cable is connected to the VNA through an SMA interface
